# Update value of IDbCommand's parameters

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I want to update value of `IDbCommand` parameters when it does exist already

```
    public void AddParameter(IDbCommand command, string name, object value)
    {
        var parameter = command.CreateParameter();
        parameter.ParameterName = "@" + name;
        parameter.Value = value;
        command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
    }
```

I tried adding this to my method but it doesn't work for `IDBCommand`, because it's a `SqlCommand` option.

```
if (command.Parameters.Contains("@" + name))
{
     command.Parameters["@" + name].Value = value;
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific then "does not work". What is happening or not happening?

Comment: IDBCommand Parameters doesn't have this option `command.Parameters["@" + name].Value`

Comment: It looks like it *should* have: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/sa8yx4sd(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to cast it to `IDbDataParameter` because `IDataParameterCollection` indexer returns an `object` type :

```
var parameterName = "@" + name;
if (command.Parameters.Contains(parameterName))
{
     var parameter = command.Parameters[parameterName] as IDbDataParameter;
     parameter.Value = value;
}
```